# Notification when Cron job is NOT normal

Tags: cron, outlook, cpanel

I have a few cron jobs that are running daily from my cPanel. Which means that 99% of the time I receive daily emails saying that everything is OK - backup is OK, xml import is OK, etc.

But what I need is a notification when the result of the cron is NOT OK - i.e. out of the ordinary. I have tried making rules in outlook, but I can't make it work.

This is for example one of my crons:

```
30 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/xx/public_html/administrator/xx/xx/backup.php -profile=1  -description="Backup"
```

I understand that 'Bash' has the possibility, but not how to practically use it.

Anyone have good ideas?

Input appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to try to set this in Outlook and not and cron job site? (serious question, I have no idea about cpanel. I know that the return value of any script on unix like OS is either 0 (no error) or non zero. YOu could trigger the mail to be send only on non-zero return values.

Comment: Cron job send email when there is an output. Dont output anything when everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper around the job, and call the wrapper from cron.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

#
# Wrapper around a backup script.
#
# Redirecting all output to a log file
# In this case to /home/xx/public_html/administrator/xx/xx/backup_job.log

#
# Lets log the start date of the job in a log file
#
echo "Starting backup job at `/bin/date`" >> /home/xx/public_html/administrator/xx/xx/backup_job.log

#
# start the backup
#
/home/xx/public_html/administrator/xx/xx/backup.php >> /home/xx/public_html/administrator/xx/xx/backup_job.log

#
# The backup job should have set a return value (0 or non-zero).
#
# If it is non-zero then there was an error. Lets send a warning mail about it
# 
#
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
 /bin/mail admin > /var/adm/backup_log

#
# Exit with a 0 value. That should indictate that this job (the wrapper) worked fine
# Usually this means cron does not have to send a mail. (But then, we already took care 
# of warning mails on our won if there was an error
#
exit 0
```